# S3 backup with a hosted server

Tags: amazon-s3, backup

I am attempting to build a backup script that moves a tar file from our hosted solution to our S3 bucket: mysitebackups. The problem that I'm running into is this: We cannot install any programs in on the server, and all the solutions I have found require various libraries and programs to be installed. The ideal solution, so far, seems to be duplicity, but this requires installation, as well as boto to be installed.

Is there a solution that requires no localized installation, or is there a way to get these to install locally without using virtualenv (which I don't have access to)?

Comment: Man, I've been looking all day for the same thing. Have you found anything over the past 7 days? This is driving me insane. One of our clients is on a shared hosting solution and I'm running into the same issue of not being able to install anything. They either require s3cmd, Duplicity or Java ...am I screwed?

Comment: So we found a solution. You can download and read about it here: [link](http://timkay.com/aws/)  It works perfectly for us, but can be a little particular and can cause odd behavior. Play with it and see if you can get it to work!

Comment: Yeah, I've actually been working with it. Seems to work great, except for the fact that it's nothing more than a tool for sending to Amazon...now the issue is getting awesome rotation working so we have multiple days of backups.

Comment: What we did is to add a date to the filename as well as a random seed to keep the files slightly more secure. This allows us to keep our backups indefinitely. Eventually we will remove files older than a certain date via the web interface and a script (I do believe) but the date in the filename really helped us out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found an answer to this. There is a Perl script that seems to work very well. It uses core libraries for perl, so it should work for you.

http://timkay.com/aws/ Thanks Tim Kay!